# Почему обновление репозитория недоступно для импорта сразу?

Tags: golang, github

Пишу пакет и выкладываю его на github.
После каждого push-а этого пакета, пытаюсь получить его обновленную верию в проекте который его использует. Но не могу получить обновленную версию по полчаса-часу. Через несколько десятков минут только получается получить обновленную версию с новыми функциями.

Пишу проект на golang и соответственно получить обновление пакета пытаюсь через  `go get -u <package name>`, когда эта команда не дает желаемого результата, то пытаюсь делать много действий  в папке проекта:

```
rm go.mod go.sum
go clean -modcache
go mod init <my/module/name>
go get <github.com/package/name>
go get -u all
go mod tidy
```

Но все равно часто не получаю обновленного пакета.

UPD:
Опубликовал новую версию пакета, попытался  сразу обновить иvмпорт в проекте, но снова не вышло и я пошел писать это сообщение. Когда написал попытался сделать импорт еще раз и получилось уже, хотя прошло минут 5-10 и ничего дополнительно не делал.
Такое чувство, как будто идет какая то модерация репозитория самим github или мой репозиторий стоит в какой-то очереди и только потом он доступен к импорту.

Answer (score 0):

Почему есть задержка так и не понял, но нашел, как принудительно загрузить новую версию пакета когда `go get -u package` не дает результата.

Нужно сделать

```
go get -u github.com.username/path/to/package@commithash
```